# How to populate only with content of getter

Tags: mongoose-populate

I have some problem in mongoose project. 
I try to populate and use getter but not all data
But now all virtuals appear in document.
I'm using `mongoose.Schema` and `mongoose.Model`

Here is example of my test code

```
const GroupsSchema = schema({
    title: String,
    users: [{
        type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users'
    }]
});

const UsersSchema = schema({
    name: String,
    avatar: String
}, {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
});

class Users extends Model {
    get name() {
        return {
           name: this.name
        };
    }
    get avatar() {
        return {
           avatar: this.avatar
        };
    }
}
```

Populating document

```
const groups = await Groups.find({}).populate('users').exec();
```

My current result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c9bb51626924f0a08aa8c3d",
    "title": "GroupName" 
    "users": [
      {
        "_id": "5c8e37169fc1f9000f8c333b",
        "name": "Jack",
        "avatar": "avatar.jpg",
        "name": {
           "name": "Jack",
        },
        "avatar": {
           "avatar": "avatar.jpg"
       }
     }
   ]
  }
]
```

How can I populate document with content of only `name` getter?

Desired result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c9bb51626924f0a08aa8c3d",
    "title": "GroupName"   
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "Jack"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Why do you have same getter, if you already have the `name` and `avatar` fields in your document, why have you created getter for them as well?

Comment: @RaviShankar This is an example, I described just simple logic by using `name` and `avatar` getter. Ok, let's imagine that `name`   getter returns name with dots as `J.A.C.K` or whatever. This is not main problem. I want to get ONLY `{ "name": "J.A.C.K"}` in populated result but not other fields.